# Formula returning #VALUE! - Remove

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've written a formula to correct strings in cells using `PROPER` formula, it looks like this:

```
=IF(SEARCH("*"&" "&"*",A1),PROPER(A1),"")
```

The problem is that when logical test is not fulfilled formula returns `#VALUE!`, I would like it to return just `""` value.

Please help.

Comment: Either use `IFERROR` to check for any error, or use the `ERROR.TYPE` function if you want to check specifically for the `#VALUE!` error

Comment: Also, you're current formula does not return a `TRUE` or `FALSE` response within your `IF` function, the `SEARCH` function will return the position of the 'search_for' text within the string you are searching. You might want to try something like: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&" "&"*",A1)),PROPER(A1),"")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your formula with `IFERROR()`. It takes two arguments **value** and **value_if_error**.
In your example it would look like `=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("\*"&" "&"\*",A1),PROPER(A1)),"")`.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you